# Преобразовать метод

Tags: android, kotlin

Вызываю метод следующим образом:

```
fun setListClickListener(listItemClickListener: ListItemClickListener?) {
    this.listItemClickListener = listItemClickListener
}
```

Сделали замечание: "use kotlin's default setter"
Не подскажет как именно можно преобразовать в дефолтный сэтер?

Пробовал делать как то так

```
fun setListClickListener(listItemClickListener: ListItemClickListener?) {
    var listItemClickListener: ListItemClickListener? = listItemClickListener
}
```

Но получается что у меня `listItemClickListener` не используется и соответственно клик не отрабатывает.

Comment: Автор, вы занимаетесь какой-то магией, а не программированием. И почему-то считаете, что здесь тоже маги, которые должны догадываться что у вас за листенер и как он должен отрабатывать взглянув на три строчки кода.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja ну вообще в программировании есть такое понятие как MDD) так что... )))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var listItemClickListener : ListItemClickListener? = null
    set(value) {field = value}
```

[Про сеттеры и геттеры](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html)

`"use kotlin's default setter"` - это, как вы правильно выразились, замечание. Вполне можно использовать и классические сеттеры, хоть это и не по феншую.

Использовать так:

```
adapter?.listItemClickListener = listItemClickListener;
```

**UPD** Конкретно в этом примере можно вообще обойтись без сеттера, а просто присваивать переменной значение, потому как `set(value) {field = value}` - это масло масляное. Собственно идеология котлина такова, что не надо плодить бессмысленные геттеры/сеттеры, которые по сути являются простыми операциями чтения/записи в свойство объекта.

Comment: Вместо value должно быть какое то значение? или я не совсем понял из перевода? (по клику на элемент по-прежнему ничего не происходит)

Comment: @Inkognito, реакция на клики ни коим боком не относится к гетерам и сеттерам.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja ну раньше из адаптера я вызывал свой метод следующим образом 
`        adapter?.setListClickListener(listItemClickListener)
` сейчас просто писать `a        adapter?.setListClickListener(listItemClickListener)
`? но он тогда не будет использоваться

Comment: @Inkognito это полностью рабочий код объявления переменной и назначения ей сеттера.

Comment: @Inkognito, это почему вы так решили?

Comment: @Inkognito по идее в адаптере вам придётся обращаться уже сразу таким образом `adapter?.listItemClickListener = listItemClickListener `

Comment: @rjhdby + конкретно в данном примере `set(value) {field = value}` это будет по-моему лишним.

Comment: @Morozov да, вы правы